# Chrome Plugin Context Menu behaves differently when Plugin is being inspected

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm working on a Google Chrome extension that stores some values in local storage when a context menu item is clicked. I'm noticing however, that the behavior of the extension is different depending on if is being inspected or not. An example plugin is as follows:

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "contextMenuTest",
  "description": "contextMenuTest",
  "version": "0.1",

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },

  "permissions": [
      "activeTab",
      "storage",
      "unlimitedStorage",
      "contextMenus",
      "notifications"
  ],

  "icons": {
      "16": "icon.png"
  }
}
```

**popup.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src= "popup.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="setContextMenuButton">Set context menu</button>
    <button id="showResultButton">Show Answer</button>
</body>
</html>
```

**popup.js**

```
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    document.getElementById("setContextMenuButton").addEventListener("click", onsetcontextmenubuttonclick);
    document.getElementById("showResultButton").addEventListener("click", onshowresultbuttonclick);
});

function onsetcontextmenubuttonclick() {
    chrome.storage.local.clear(function() {
        chrome.contextMenus.removeAll(function() {
            chrome.contextMenus.create(
                {
                    "title": "test",
                    "contexts": ["selection"],
                    "onclick": function(info, tab) {
                        chrome.storage.local.set({"test":"test"});
                    }
                }
            );
        });
    });
}

function onshowresultbuttonclick() {
    chrome.storage.local.get("test", function(items) {
        console.log(items);
    });
}
```

The expected behavior occurs when inspecting the popup: inspect the popup, click the "Set Context Menu" button, select some text and right click it, click "test" in the context menu, then inspect the popup and click the "Show Answer" button. chrome.storage.local.set() set the value for "test", so chrome.storage.local.get() is able to retrieve it properly and display {test: "test"}.

However, when carrying out the same steps without the first step of inspecting the popup, {} is displayed instead, implying that chrome.storage.local.set() did not properly set the value for "test" when the popup was not being inspected.

There is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7133185/google-chrome-behaves-differently-when-the-popup-is-being-inspected), but it didn't quite answer my question.

Why would the context menu behave differently depending on if the plugin is being inspected or not, and how would I fix this?

Comment: chrome.contextMenus.removeAll() is asynchronous so you may hit a race condition. Move your create function inside the callback of removeAll.

Comment: Ah, good call. I've edited the code as you've suggested.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to be on-topic: include a [mcve] that *duplicates the problem*. For Chrome extensions or Firefox WebExtensions you almost always need to include your *manifest.json* and some of the background, content, and/or popup scripts/HTML, and often webpage HTML/scripts. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't my code working the way I want?") must include: (1) the desired behavior, (2) a specific problem or error and (3) the shortest code necessary to reproduce it *in the question itself*. Please also see: [What topics can I ask about here?](/help/on-topic), and [ask].

Comment: Note: [`chrome.storage.local.clear()`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage#StorageArea-methods) is *also* asynchronous. Thus, you have another race condition where the storage may be cleared after you set it.

Comment: I've added the manifest and html files, and given more clear steps to reproduce the problem. I've also wrapped the code following chrome.storage.local.clear() in the function's callback, as per your comments.